# Collecting user password via GUI in a script

Tags: scripts, ssh, sudo, password, su

I know that using the `sudo` and `ssh` tools it is possible to use GUI to ask for a password in a script by setting, respectively, the `SUDO_ASKPASS` and `SSH_ASKPASS` variables in which we specify a graphical tool to ask a password.

But what if I am using **any other tool** which may ask for a password, for example `ksu` which does not seem to support any of the above-mentioned modes? (I searched on internet and I did not find anything like `KSU_ASKPASS` and `ksu` does not seem to have any option to support this).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the solution at the end...

Suppose, for example, that you want to list the contents of the `/root/` folder and in order to do this you need a root access and you can only use the `ksu` tool (no `sudo` / `su` / `ssh`).

First, you ask the password using a graphical tool like `zenity` and you store it in a local variable.

```
pw=$(zenity --entry --title="Password needed" --text="Enter password:" --hide-text)
```

After that, you can run `ls /root/` via `ksu` by using the following command.

```
echo $pw | ksu -e /bin/ls -a /root/
```

Explanation:

- By using `echo` combined with `|` you are piping the password to `ksu`, since it asks for a password via the standard input.
- After reading the password from the standard input, `ksu` executes the `ls` command specified using the `-e` option, passing `/root/` as an argument via the `-a` option.